# iOS: How do I get zip code from a placemark

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkplacemark

I am wondering how I might be able to get the placemark's zip code in iOS. Any tips or suggestions will be deeply appreciated. Here is the code I have so far, I am able to get the city.

```
 - (void)recenterMapToPlacemark:(CLPlacemark *)placemark {
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;

span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;

region.span = span;
region.center = placemark.location.coordinate;

NSString *city = [placemark locality];

 }
```

Comment: Have you tried something like this :  NSString *zipCode = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];

Comment: @AbhishekMukherjee You have a typo in your comment, you are missing a * sign after the NSString cast. However this isn't the right way to do it. Check the answer I  posted.

Comment: @DominikHadl It is not a NSString cast but a declaration. I typed the code at office. I hope the person asking the question got it working though.

Comment: @AbhishekMukherjee I was referencing the `(NSString)kAB..` part, which is a cast and should be `(NSString *)kAB...`. But now as you write it, I've noticed you are also missing a `*` in the declaration (meaning `NSString zipCode` should be `NSString *zipCode`).

Comment: @DominikHadl Thanks for pointing that out, but I already know that, it baffled me that even after saying I just typed the code in a non XCode environment, you still had to go through listing out missing *s.What was asked can also be achieved by kABPersonAddressZIPKey route. Not sure what prompted your comment of "not the right way to do it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLPlacemark/postalCode

It is the `postalCode` property you are looking for.
So in your case it is:

`NSString *zipCode = placemark.postalCode;`

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the document.